# Current loop Circuit isolation

Tags: ground, current-source, isolation

I am using xtr117 current loop transmitter in my current project. I am planning to generate the current loop from xtr117 followed by a DAC 0 to 5v output But the grounds of the loop supply and IRET pin must be isolated.
Is there any method to isolate using minimum no of components. I am attaching my the circuit also
[image]

loop supply is provided in series to the loop.
need to isolate the IRET and cl_o1 and also dac's gnd pin (Dac's gnd and loop supply gnd can be connect as chassis ground)

Comment: Do you mean 'following' rather than 'followed by'????? What is the whole system, your diagram and concerns make no sense at the moment. By focussing on just the DAC and the current driver components, you have lost the context that would allow anyone to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. resistance path in your transmitter is to much high (1200 ohm). The TVS diode between +24V and ANA output won't have any function. For example if a spike occurs at ANA output, then the only free path across the TVS is into the driver chip, since you have a polarity protection diode. You could place two TVS diodes: one at input +24V and the other on ANA line, both to earth.
2. The sensing resistor goes on the receiver part (near ADC).
3. The easiest way of making isolated DAQ is to put the entire ADC section over the isolating barrier. You need a DC/DC isolating converter and opto or magnetic signal isolators for CLK, SDA